# I want to reduce Internet Speed while opening my Own App for testing purpose?

Tags: android, performance, testing, download, upload

Is there any app for android that lets me control speed of net? I need control download and upload speed by increase and decrease the speed. I need to control my ping too!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use one of sniffers for you goal. For example Fiddler ore Charles Proxy. This is very powerful and strong tools.
In other wise you can simple use android studio simulator abilities for control needed parametres. Loock at screens below

[image]

[image]